# An action before another in a Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want that when I click on "nav-toggle" it adds the toggle class "open" to "grappa". Then I would like to remove the toggle class "open" clicking anywhere on the web page.

I wrote this but it doesn't working.

```
$(function() {
        $('.nav-toggle').on('click', function(){
            $('.grappa').toggleClass('open');{
                $(document).click(function() {
                $('.grappa').toggleClass('close');
             });
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Please explain full behavior expected and provide sample html structure. See [mcve]

Comment: Why are you nesting the second click?

Comment: Question ? give some more details

Comment: I updated it. see if you can understand... @Tharun

Comment: What you have posted isn't valid JavaScript.  Are you trying to toggle the `close` class only after the `open` class has been toggled?  Your questions doesn't mention the `close` class at all.

Comment: Yes, you understood what I need! @EricG

Comment: This is still not properly detailed and you are already having to add comments to answers because you have not explained properly the **complete** expected behavior or provided any html sample

Comment: @NiccolòGuidi let me know if my answer below didn't solve your problem.  Haven't heard from you in a few days and I wanted to make sure we had a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Write separate events

To Toggle

```
  $('.nav-toggle').on('click', function(){
        $('.grappa').toggleClass('open');
    });
```

Any where on web page click

```
$( document.body ).click(function() {
    $('.grappa').toggleClass('close');
});
```

Keep Alert/Console statements to your script is getting called.Referencing js in your web page should be correct

Updated

Look at this Fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/M4teA/

Comment: In this way it doesn't work because .nav-toggle is in the body and clicking there does both functions. I think the solution is to enable the second function only after the .nav-toggle is clicked the first time

Comment: have added Fiddle. May help your case

Answer (score 0):

You could check if your `grappa` element has the `open` class before toggling the `close` class.  Then the `close` class would only be toggled if `open` had already been toggled.  Something like:

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav-toggle').on('click', function(){
        $('.grappa').toggleClass('open');
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        if ($('.grappa').hasClass('open'))
        {
            $('.grappa').toggleClass('close');
        }
    });

});
```

Also, since I haven't seen any of your css or html I'm not exactly sure how you are using the `open` and `close` classes but it appears that it might make more sense to just add and remove the `open` class depending on if the element has that class.  Something like:

```
$(document).click(function() {
     if ($('.grappa').hasClass('open'))
     {
          $('.grappa').removeClass('open');
     }
});
```